# Macro slow when other Excel files are open

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen other users post somewhat the same question, but the core problem doesn't seem to be the same (as far as I can tell).

I have an Excel workbook that goes through about 80 000 rows and four columns of data. This takes about 1-2 seconds at the most. The workbook does do operations in other worksheets but for the test I have turned those subs off. If I open an .xlsx of about 10 Mb it takes a bit longer but not much. If I open up an .xlsm with some considerable code, it takes about 6-7 seconds to do the same thing.

What I have read so far is that one should use set variables of ranges instead of cell references, calculation set to manual, screenupdating off. None of these seem to do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

If the events were not disabled, this could also be added just before the code begins:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Changing it to True when everything is finished.

If you wish to optimize things further, one possibility is to assign it to a variable:

```
Dim Temp as Variant
Temp = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

Analyze and change Temp, and then put it back

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange = Temp
```

Comment: That could defenititely be it. The WB relies a lot on EnableEvents. The users change date or costcentre with the help of Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range). It will take me a day or two, but I'll make sure to post an update.

Many thanks Demetri.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The enableevents = false didn't work. Haven't tried the variant version yet. I'll make sure to reply once I've tried it and other solutions. Many thanks, Mugs

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. It has to do with instances of Excel. If multiple heavy macro files are opened in the same instance of Excel it takes a lot longer than if one instance per file is used. I don't know why this is, but from what I've read it's a bug that's been around since Office 2003 or something.

So now all I have to do is make sure that everyone uses multiple instances. Unfortunately you have to do some register changes to make that happen automatically. I'm currently going with the .bat file alternative.

Comment: Please do not post "thanks" as an answer to the question. Once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you'll be able to [upvote questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.